# angular can't call functions/variables inside a function

Tags: angular, typescript, function, google-maps

I am using **google.maps.geocoder** to get a location request in my angular app. In a request I provide a callback function with results. now if I want to call my other function which displays the marker on map the code breaks unexpectedly. I also can not set any variables defined on my component, it looks like every global variable/function is undefined when the code in the Geocoder callback function is happening.

How can I fix this and get data from my callback function in my app?

```
googleMapsFindLocation() {
        var address = this.locationName;

        this.geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                var mapCustomObj = new MapCustomObj();
                var marker = {
                    position: { lat: 46, lng: 16 },
                    info:
                        '<h2>' + "tekst" + '</h2></br>' +
                        '<p>' + "" + '</p>' +
                        '<p>' + "this.raceDto.seasonName" + '</p>' +
                        '<p>' + "this.raceDto.lat" + ' - ' + "this.raceDto.long" + '</p>'
                };
                mapCustomObj.marker = marker;

                //HERE IS THE PROBLEM. If i call showMap the code breaks, and the code in my showMap doesnt even get hit in debug
                this.showOnMap(mapCustomObj);

            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your callback to an arrow function: from `function (results, status) { }` to `(results, status) => { }` . the issue is when the callback will be called `this` will be the global object, not the component. but arrow functions bind `this` to its current context where it's declared.

Tip: don't declare variables with `var`. prefer `const` first, `let` second.

Tip2: since the object `{ 'address': address }` has the same key and variable naming you can pass as `{ address }`